# is there something similar to std::quote for multiple characters like ETX/STX pairs

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++17

I see there is a function in `<iomanip>` for quoting a *single* char out and in a std::string. I search something similar to that for multiple characters. My current use case is to masquerade STX / ETX pairs in/out a string.

Use for `std::quote` is easy like:

```
std::string example{ "Hallao" };
std::cout << std::quoted(example, 'a', 'x') << std::endl;
```

So my wish to see is something like:

```
std::cout << std::quoted(example, {0x02,0x03}, ...) << std::endl;
```

Is that already done somewhere or is this to special to be a part of STL?

Comment: And which character should go at the front and at the back of the quoted string?

Comment: It's not a very common operation and it's also not very difficult to implement if you want it. (To me, `quoted` is a bit strange to find in a standard library, and its name even stranger. I blame young people.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, so far there isn't. The delim and escape chars are restricted to *one* character. You can't use multiple chars or string under the current interface.

This unnecessary limitation applies to a lot of components too :( (for example the `isalpha` family of functions)